# Is there a light alternative to jQuery Mobile for just page transitions?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for an **ULTRA-light** framework or snippet which handles `-webkit` css page transitions in a similar way to JQM or JQTouch. They work fine but I don't want to add almost 200kb of resources just to get some transitions.

I'd like it to feature :

**1** Page-to-page switching (divs) within a single HTML-doucment.

**2** Do a 'flip' and possibly a 'slide' transition.

Has anyone seen such a thing?

Edit: I'd like to avoid using jQuery all together.

Comment: Have you looked at [Jo](http://joapp.com)?

Comment: Yes! Not really what I was looking for..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update, found this:

http://www.fasw.ws/faswwp/non-jquery-page-transitions-lightweight/

Looks as if this guy has been able to (almost) extract JQM's transitions to a stand-alone script..

Inspired by this I wrote this script which flips between pages: http://jsfiddle.net/AAfek/47

```
Use document.querySelector or querySelectorAll instead of using document.all.tags
```

Works a treat for my purposes..

Comment: Fiddle is broken, window.onload error.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/dgileadi/zepto-page-transitions - great, great stuff!

Answer (score 1):

**PageSlider.js** is an extremely lightweight mini lib that handles page transitions in single page apps.

It's made by an Adobe employee Christophe Coenraets and it pretty thoroughly tested

https://github.com/ccoenraets/PageSlider

Answer (score 1):

Here you are: https://github.com/linslin/pagingSlider a new page slider plugin based on Christophe Coenraets - comes with some features like:

- Paging with pagingSlider
- default pageSlider actions
- Pagebrowser
- Totaly plugable like pageSlider
- if you want, pagemenu to switch directly to a page

HF

Answer (score 0):

U can check out a lightweight page flip jquery at: 
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/14/moleskine-notebook/

They have included few images with the script, u can avoid them to obtain even lesser size.

I guess this is the effect you are looking for using CSS -webkit transformations:

> [flip effect with webkit animation](http://line25.com/articles/super-cool-css-flip-effect-with-webkit-animation)

Comment: Yeah, not really the kind of flipping I was referring to, thanks though.

Comment: Wat kind of flip or slide u want, any demo page u got on normal jquery?

Comment: the kind of flip often seen in mobile applications, for example in [JQM](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-transitions.html)

Comment: that's more like the effect I want, although I would love to have seen some code making it a more general function (intended for switching pages in a mobile app), not just a css hover effect.

Comment: I agree you'll have to modify the script to suit your requirement. You can achieve the same effect by altering the script by changing :hover to clickEffect using javascript to trigger the flip effect.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a need to have a JS framework just to use CSS3 transitions/animations. Have a look here for a collection of great animations/transitions: https://daneden.me/animate/

All you need to activate such a transition  is something like:

```
$('#yourPAgeContainingElement').addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');
```